# Self executable PHP files

Tags: php, compilation, binary

I'm writing some scripts in PHP for mangling data etc and I would like to be able to hand these over to our client to run without all the overhead of them having to install PHP first.

I was wondering if there's a way to bundle PHP itself with a script to create an exe file? This sounds like I might have to compile php in a clever way of some kind and get it to run itself with the file argument when it's executed.

Is there something out there to do this? It'd be really handy! I understand you'd end up with a fairly big executable because of the overhead of having the php executable bundled within it, but I think the benefits outweigh the down sides.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks,
John.

Comment: There are a lot of these "PHP to EXE" things out there. Im not sure if they run standalone or if they need PHP to be installed. Maybe you should just try it out.

Comment: Also you really should reconsider of your approach is the right one: if you now already face a general issue that you do not know how to deploy your result in a way that it can actually be used, then _maybe_ you should use another platform? I mean php simply is not meant for this... Actually _no_ scripting engine is meant for such use, it is against the idea behind the scripting approach.

Comment: I realise this isn't the best language for doing such a thing, but it's far easier for the company to support PHP than for our developers to have to learn python or something if something goes wrong.